# Basic Authentication in Retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit2, аутентификация, response

Есть URL получения данных:
http://ps1722.weeteam.net/api/products?display=[name,description,id_default_image,price,reference]&limit=20

Авторизация – Basic:

login: XHKM6A6BLCA5MNYZQBX2GXBAAKSTPMK2

password: без пароля

Метод кодировки Basic:

```
public static String getAuthToken() {
        byte[] data = new byte[0];
        try {
            data = ("login" + ":" + "password").getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Как получить данные по ссылке.

Использую Retrofit2:

```
public interface APIService {

        @GET("api/productsdisplay=[name,description,id_default_image,price,reference]&limit=20")
        Call<ResponseBody> callBack (@Header("Authorization") String credential);

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrofit использует OkHttp в качестве http-клиента. Вам для Basic авторизации  достаточно такого кода:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .authenticator((route, response) -> {
            Request request = response.request();
            if (request.header("Authorization") != null)
                // Логин и пароль неверны
                return null;
            return request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic("login", "password"))
                    .build();
        })
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        ...
        .build();
```

Учтите, что в данном коде можно использовать только заранее зашитую пару логин/пароль,если вам нужна поддержка разных, то стоит создать отдельный класс, имплементирующий [Authenticator](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить header - Authorization: Basic XHKM6A6BLCA5MNYZQBX2GXBAAKSTPMK2 при запросах, точно сказать как его вставить не могу в вашем случае, не знаю какой клиент вы используете.

Comment: Использую Retrofit2:        public interface APIService {

    @GET("api/productsdisplay=[name,description,id_default_image,price,reference]&limit=20")
    Call<ResponseBody> callBack (@Header("Authorization") String credential);

}

Comment: RequestInterceptor нужно использовать для инъекции токена в header - [доки](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header)